# Show item from a array only to admins

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this array:

```
$avia_pages = array(
    array('slug' => 'avia',   'parent'=>'avia', 'icon'=>"new/spanner-screwdriver-7@3x.png" , 'title' =>  __('Theme Options', 'avia_framework')),
    array('slug' => 'layout', 'parent'=>'avia', 'icon'=>"new/window-within-7@3x.png",        'title' =>  __('General Layout', 'avia_framework')), 
);
```

And i need to show this only to admin. I tried using if

```
(if (is_super_admin()) {
    array('slug' => 'layout',  'parent'=>'avia', 'icon'=>"new/window-within-7@3x.png", 'title' =>  __('General Layout', 'avia_framework')),
}
```

But it wont work, i got PHP errors.

For further information i'm using Enfold Theme in a Wordpress 5.1

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to set the array to a variable.

Comment: What errors? [Edit] the question and make it clear what you want to do, show what you have tried, and show your results. See [ask].

Comment: not quite certain if that's what you ask, but if you want to check if the current user has administrator rights you can do this: if(current_user_can('administrator')) { // do your admin stuff };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) passing as parameter the role administrator.

```
<?php if( current_user_can('administrator') ) { ?> 
    // stuff here for admins
<?php } else { ?>
    // stuff here for not admins
<?php } ?>
```

However, current_user_can can be used not only with users role name, but also with capabilities.

```
<?php if( current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) { ?> 
    // stuff here for user roles that can edit pages: editors and 
administrators
<?php } ?>
```

Have a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for more info on capabilities.